# Almacenar coordenadas en MySQL

Tags: mysql, google-maps, geolocalización

En su experiencia, como es mejor guardar coordenadas en mysql, he visto en algunos artículos que recomiendan usar float o decimal y otros usar point.

Que método tiene menores errores o cual es más eficiente.

En un documento vi

```
lat FLOAT( 10, 6 ) NOT NULL,  
lng FLOAT( 10, 6 ) NOT NULL
```

y en otro

```
lat DECIMAL( 10, 8 ) NOT NULL,  
lng DECIMAL( 11, 8 ) NOT NULL
```

Como dato, usare la información para poder ver ubicaciones de la API Google Maps y poder hacer consultas de ubicaciones en un radio del mapa.

Quisiera saber si alguna vez han trabajado con alguno, o ambos y que ventajas o desventajas tienen. Gracias.

Comment: He trabajado con coordenadas en mysql en tipo float y me ha resultado sin problemas. También lo pudieras almacenar en forma de texto para evitar problemas en los datos.

Comment: Pero, para cálculos, que tan eficiente es?

Comment: Que tipo de cálculos deseas hacer?

Comment: Calcular ubicaciones en un ratio determinado. Por decir, estoy en Madrid, quiero ver las casas que estan a 20K a la redonda. Casas previamente registradas en la base de datos.

Comment: Realmente no se ve diferencia entre uno y otro el performance. Pudieras tener problemas es de la base de datos pero ya depende de las consultas que hagas ya que mysql es algo lento.

Comment: Usa el tipo de dato `POINT`  pues este mismo tiene una función `ST_distance` para calcular diantancias entre 2 puntos

Comment: Pero usando texto se puede hacer cálculos matemáticos?

Comment: Y para calcular ubicaciones en un ratio determinado. Por decir, estoy en Madrid, quiero ver las casas que estan a 20K a la redonda. Casas previamente registradas en la base de datos. 

Es que leeí por algún lado que cuando usas POINT debes contar con consultas especiales o algo así, mi temor era que mi servidor no tuviera eso.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Mysql estás usando?

Comment: En que lenguaje vas a consumir tu base de datos.

Comment: En PHP es para una web app usando la API de Google Maps

Comment: Claro se pueden hacer cálculos basta con pasarle un (float) y listo. Ejemplo: $lat = (float) "-101.12434"

Comment: Calculos desde MYSQL